# URL redirection depending on logged in or not

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a logo and I want it to redirect to a homepage when the user is logged in or to a register site when the user is not logged in.

Here is my code:

```
<strong class="logo">
    <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) ?>
    <a href="http://test/register/">
    <?php else ?>
    <a href="<?php echo home_url();?>">

    <img id="logo_img" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" src="<?php echo $logo_path; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
```

I'm using Wordpress. It says `unexpected "else"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing your if / else statements correctly:

```
<strong class="logo">
                <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
                <a href="http://test/register/">
                <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo home_url();?>">
                <?php } ?>

            <img id="logo_img" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" src="<?php echo $logo_path; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
```

if you want to use this in a way for no brackets you have to do something like this:

```
<strong class="logo">
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in())
    echo '<a href="http://test/register/">';
else
    echo '<a href="'.home_url().'">';
?>

<img id="logo_img" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" src="<?php echo $logo_path; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<strong class="logo">
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in())
 {
 echo '<a href="http://demo.com/register-path/">';
 }
 else
 {
 echo '<a href="'.home_url().'">';
 }
echo '<img src="logo-path.png"></a>';
?>
```

`